# AICC standards documents and sample package

Tags: standards, scorm

I'm reading about some learning management system (LMS) standards and found that SCORM and AICC are quite common nowadays. I have tried to find things related to them. With SCORM, it is easy, but with AICC, all things I have found via Google are pointed to the AICC's home page which is now nothing except "Goodbye" message. Anyone can please help me find AICC things (**standard explanation, sample code of a content player that complies the standard, programming guide, and sample course content package**). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitive (and official) collection of AICC documentation:
https://github.com/ADL-AICC/AICC-Document-Archive

(Found via Google, keywords "AICC documentation")

Side note: The AICC organization has recently disbanded due to dwindling membership. If you're interested in learning about LMS standards, the most widely supported (and easiest to learn) standard is SCORM 1.2.

SCORM 2004 was released to address some of the shortcomings with SCORM 1.2, but wound up introducing new issues. It's powerful and worth using, but you need to learn its quirks and pitfalls to avoid.

As the name implies, SCORM 2004 is now a decade old. xAPI (aka Tin Can) was introduced as a potential replacement, and borrows elements from both AICC and SCORM. It is not widely supported yet, but is worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for your link @pipwerks. Have you got reference to any sample of AICC (a sample course content package or an application which obeys AICC standards) for me to comprehend AICC more easily ?  Yes SCORM is highly recommended but as I've read, SCORM borrows lesson-server communication from AICC then I still have to read more about AICC.

Comment: If you're only looking at AICC because you've read SCORM borrows some elements from AICC, then you're better off looking directly at SCORM.

Comment: SCORM is actually a compilation of specs/standards. It uses AICC's data model (CMI data model) but that's about the only connection. Honestly, no one uses AICC, and the difficulty you're having finding examples proves the point. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

AICC is now officially closed. A newer version of AICC Standard is now called CMI5 which uses Tin Can API (also known as Experience API or xAPI).

You can see the CMI5 Spec at https://github.com/AICC/CMI-5_Spec_Current/blob/quartz/cmi5_runtime.md